# Syntax error on token "else," delete this token

Tags: java, if-statement

I am new to java and I can not figure out why there is a syntax error here.  I have copied and pasted the code, and I commented where the error is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CountryDetails {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter any of the following integers to see details of the corresponding country:(1, 36, 57, 94, 250, 269, 354, 376, 597, 678, 962, 992)");
    //prompt reader to enter a number
    int code=input.nextInt();

    int x;
    x=input.nextInt();
    if ((x!=1)&&(x!=36)&&(x!=57)&&(x!=94)&&(x!=250)&&(x!=269)&&(x!=354)&&(x!=376)&&(x!=597)&&(x!=678)&&(x!=962)&&(x!=992)); {
      System.out.println("You did not enter one of the possible integers.");
    }

    else if (x==1) { //error is here
      System.out.println("Enter amount in US dollars:"); //prompt reader to enter US dollars
      double dollars = input.nextDouble(); //reading input
      double exchangeRate= dollars*45.72;

      //display results
      System.out.println ("1 is the Country Calling Code for the Dominican Republic, which is located in the Americas");
      System.out.println (+dollars+ " is equivalent to " +exchangeRate+ "Dominican Pesos.");
    }
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You might want to consider creating a list of integers (e.g. `List<Integer> countries = Arrays.asList(36, 57, 94 /* etc */);`), which will allow you to simplify your condition to `if (!countries.contains(x)) {`, and just use `countries.toString()` in your message (e.g. `System.out.println("Enter any of the following... " + countries + ":")`).

Answer (score 3):

By your long if statement, get rid of the semicolon at the end.

```
// The semicolon at the end of this line
if ((x!=1)&&(x!=36)&&(x!=57)&&(x!=94)&&(x!=250)&&(x!=269)&&(x!=354)&&(x!=376)&&(x!=597)&&(x!=678)&&(x!=962)&&(x!=992)); {
    System.out.println("You did not enter one of the possible integers.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-if-statements-in-java.html) on how `if` and `if-else` statements work in `java`. Consider the below two cases in java.

**Case #1**

```
if (boolean-expression)
    statement
```

**Case #2**

```
if (boolean-expression-1)
{
        statement-1
        statement-11
        statement-111
}
else
{
        statement-2
        statement-22
}
```

Every statement in `java` ends with a `;`. And a `;` by itself is valid and it is an empty statement which does nothing. In your code, you meant to write an `if-else` condition which has to look like **Case-2** but due to the erroneous `;`, `java` treats it as **Case-1** and it throws an error when it encounters the keyword `else`.

In your sample code, `java` compiler thinks of the semicolon in the end of if condition as an empty statement. But `else` always need to come along with an `if` statement. Change the `if` condition to look like below by removing `;` -

```
if ((x!=1)&&(x!=36)&&(x!=57)&&(x!=94)&&(x!=250)&&(x!=269)&&(x!=354)&&(x!=376)&&(x!=597)&&(x!=678)&&(x!=962)&&(x!=992)) {
      System.out.println("You did not enter one of the possible integers.");
    }
```